# Android app with Zendesk SDK crashing with java no such field error

Tags: android, zendesk, zendesk-app

I am using ZENDESK Android SDK and trying to open the support activity like this :

```
new com.zendesk.sdk.support.SupportActivity.Builder().listCategories().show(this);
```

But it crashes with the following error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field support_search_input of type I in class Lcom/zendesk/sdk/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.zendesk.sdk.R$id' appears in /data/data/nl.tirato.RoomEasy/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex)
at com.zendesk.sdk.support.SupportActivity.onCreate(SupportActivity.java:205)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

I am using the latest sdk :

```
compile group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.6.1.1'
compile group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk-providers', version:'1.6.1.1'
```

My activity is extending *AppCompatActivity*

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you also have a definition for support_search_input in your resource files? It could be a clash in the naming.

Comment: No, actually when I go the line number where the crash occurred. It takes me to the zendesk library class where there is a field named support_search_input

Comment: I've only ever seen this issue when there are duplicated names like this. is support_search_input defined in any other library that you are using?

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right. The crash was because , the name of one of my layout files and one of the libraries layout files was same.
Once you asked me if there is also this field in anwhere else. 
I ran a search and at that time I found out that the name of layout files were same. So, instead of inflating the library layout file , my layout file was being inflated and resulted in an error.

Comment: Good to hear :) I hope the rest of your integration goes well!

Answer (score 0):

Hi just Replace dependency with version `compile group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.10.0.1'`